# Celery Segmentation Fault

Tags: python, gdb, celery

What can I do, when process (celery worker) causes a segmentation fault error?
In my case problem raises in celery, but I don't know how to find which module(used in tasks) has a corrupted code.
Link to some additional info about problem — https://github.com/ask/celery/issues/690.
In other words which command in gdb could give useful info, or other recipes to resolve this problem.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: The link gives a 404, I think this is the update: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/690

Answer (score 5):

This might help:

[Install python-amqp package and remove python-librabbitmq](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=736348#10)

On Ubuntu, it appears the latest APT package version of python-librabbitmq is 1.0.3 which is too older than the last release (1.5.1).  You may install the latest one by pip instead of apt-get:

```
sudo pip install -U librabbitmq
```

Comment: This fixed it for me once I checked all possible locations for librabbitmq.

Answer (score -2):

I had similar problem, and it was solved after deleting .celerybeat file.

Comment: From where? What was in this file?