# Segmentation fault (core dumped) celery python

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I have a python application using celery with rabbitmq broker. when I run workers it does some random number of tasks and then raise an error:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I also installed librabbitmq==1.6.1 but it didn't help. How can I solve this?

Comment: Can add more traceback error?

Comment: @ManojJadhav it doesn't have any traceback.

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847620/celery-segmentation-fault

Comment: @ManojJadhav I installed the latest version of librabbitmq but it didn't help